# Minting NFTs via cardano-cli: How to mint several NFTs consecutively?

Tags: cardano-cli, nft, minting

I followed the NFT minting docs on https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts which works very well for the first transaction.

I'm currently stuck trying to mint a second NFT. It's not clear to me, what kind of data has to be regenerated and what needs to be kept for the cli commands their parameters.

for the second transaction I've tried with and without regenerating policy keys and policyID. I adjusted the `txhash` and `funds` values, as those have changed after the first transaction. nothing really works.

here is the error I'm getting:

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 999813423 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "b5c707bc10063ae8ab04c2f7b99c3ed1f0bdd82266369367a7bef050"},fromList [("NFT1",1)]),(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "fcd60019e5c25602201d5a28f73b7749e85efab6a31dbb7aa461132b"},fromList [("NFT1",1)])])) (Value 999813423 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "b5c707bc10063ae8ab04c2f7b99c3ed1f0bdd82266369367a7bef050"},fromList [("NFT1",1)])])))))])
```

I hope someone can give me advice what kind of parameters need to change after the first transaction is done.

best

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not providing more context and code / scripts in the original question. however, I found the solution to my problem and want to share it in case anyone else has a similar issue.

for the very first transaction from/to a given address, the `--tx-out` param looked something like this:

`--tx-out addr_test1vqjf8aak5fn3u2la4dgwyda98s2py3f9pqcmnhfq93ugq0qkctw7v+0+1 "90fa8ff2fb851f92fd239574334a37762bc22dcdf0595a269ad300c8.NFT1"`

which is basically `$address+$fees+"$tokenamount $policyID.$tokenname"`

for the second transaction I just tried to replace `$fees`, `$tokenamount`, `$policyID` and `$tokenname`with values from another NFT. what I didn't know is that `$tokenamount`, `$policyID` and `$tokenname` of the first transaction (or from all previous transactions) also have to be appended to the new value for the `--tx-out` param. so it would look like this:

`--tx-out addr_test1vqjf8aak5fn3u2la4dgwyda98s2py3f9pqcmnhfq93ugq0qkctw7v+0+1 "90fa8ff2fb851f92fd239574334a37762bc22dcdf0595a269ad300c8+NFT1" "1 9bb49c25ea28964c96d119ecb3a9425d39a390e6c34974f2637c750e.NFT2`

best

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until transaction is finished and UTxO's are updated in your wallet.

A way to do it is to create a script that will query UTxO's for your wallet and once UTxO's are changed you run next transaction.

You can query it either directly from CLI and parse the results, or you can query it via [cardano-graphql](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql) or [Blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/) API.