# How to create a project of many NFTs in one shot?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, nft

I have a collection of pictures, which I would like to list as NFTs on a popular NFT marketplace. I followed the official [tutorial](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts/) on Cardano developers website, however, the example shows the creation of just one NFT.

Does a repository, or some other source exist, which could guide me through the process of creation of multiple NFTs in one shot? I've seen [one answer](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3731/minting-nfts-via-cardano-cli-how-to-mint-several-nfts-consecutively) to my question but it seems to be not very convenient way when the number of NFTs to be minted is high (i.e. 100, 1000, 10000).

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The [CIP25: NFT Metadata Standard](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/) allows you to specify multiple asset names, but keep in mind, you need to include the metadata in the transaction itself so you will never be able to list a high amount of this metadata, certainly not over a 100.

If you do not use the onchain metadata, but rather store your NFT metadata off-chain in [the Cardano Foundation registry](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry), you might be able to mint much more tokens in one shot.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Out of curiosity, how does it relate to storing metadata on IPFS system like Pinata or Blockfrost? Do I have to store it in the registry or can I use third party service like the ones mentioned?

Comment: At the moment, both off-chain and on-chain metadata are not stored on IPFS, just the "content" of the NFT.